# conjure-up error ubuntu 16.04 - neutron-gateway config-changed

Tags: networking, juju, openstack, conjure-up

I am trying to install openstack on multiple hp blc460 g7, 1 x MAAS & 5 nodes , however I tried several times and it's always blocking. The error is "neutron-gateway/0 hook failed: config-changed", but it's also blocked because of ceph-osd/(0,1,2) - no block devices detected using current configuration.

[Conjure-up errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydBjF.png)

Here is the juju status in yaml format:

https://pastebin.com/xBtvGckM

Please help us.

Answer (score 0):

You could add "net.ifnames=0" on kernel boot parameters (MAAS settings) and check the name consistency of MAAS nodes' interfaces.

Running conjure-up, using openstack with NOVAKVM spell you can enter the configure option on neutron-gateway unit, section "data-port" and change the default interface value (eno2) to one of the interfaces of your MAAS nodes.

Maybe it´s worth to check:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/conjure-up/+bug/1626941
and
This [link](https://jujucharms.com/neutron-gateway/238) under "Port configuration" section.

No sure if ceph-OSD issues are related to the neutron-gateway one.

Comment: Please add a bit more background information and a step by step instructions on how to change things.